# Is there a chance to overwrite existing variable inside post function in Node.js when a new connection? (Express.js)

Tags: node.js, express

Maybe it's a silly question... But I'm sorry that I still want to ask this:

For example (code):

```
const express = require('express');
app = express();
...
app.post('/form', function(req, res) {
    var title = req.body.title;
    var content = req.body.content;
    //doing something here...
}
```

(In action):
**User A** post to /form with some JSON data { "title": "hello", "content": "world" }
a very very short time later (let's say 1ms)
**User B** post to /form with different JSON data { "title": "sup", "content": "nothing" }

The real question is:
Will user B be able to overwrite the value of existing variables (title & content)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No as javascript is single threaded. Each request is turn-by-turn processed, sometimes if one processing involves time-consuming stuff (like db fetch), the call back will be pushed to event loop, to be executed after the time-consuming task finishes.

However, you can update a global variable and override it from another request. Since your variables are in function scope they wont be overridden. Each function invocation will have its own closed scope.